# Find the matrix representation of a specific linear transformaion

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Linear transformation$\ T:\ \mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2
> > $stretches everything that is along the line $y=-\frac{1}{2}x$ by 3 and
>   everything along the line $y=4x$ by -2.

I am looking to find the matrix representation A of the linear tranformation
where $A=[T]_β$  Where 
     $\beta=\left\{\left[\matrix{1\cr0\cr}\right],\left[\matrix{0\cr1\cr}\right]\right\}$

I'm not quite sure how to approach this problem, I've tried picking vectors on the lines $y=-\frac{1}{2}x$ $y=4x$ and see what happens to them and constructing the matrix that way. But that has led me down a dead end..

Could I get a hint on how to approach this problem? I can't think of a systematic way to find a linear transformation based on information like this.

Do I just pick two points one on  $y=-\frac{1}{2}x$ & one on $y=4x$ and create a system of linear equations and solve it?

I believe I'd get the four equations $2a−b=6$ & $2c−d=−3$ & $a+4b=−2$ & $c+4d=−8$

Comment: Have you learned about changes of basis yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$u=\left(\matrix{1\cr -\frac 1 2  \cr}\right)$ on line1

$v=\left(\matrix{1\cr4\cr}\right)$ on line 2
$$e_1=\left(\matrix{1\cr0\cr}\right)=\frac 1 9 (8u+v)$$
$$f(e_1)=\frac 1 9(8f(u)+f(v))$$
$$f(e_1)=\frac 1 9(24u-2v)$$
$$f(e_1)=\frac 1 9\left(\matrix{22\cr-20\cr}\right)$$

$$e_2=\left(\matrix{0\cr1\cr}\right)=\frac 2 9 (v-u)$$
$$f(e_2)=\frac 2 9(f(u)-f(v))$$
$$f(e_2)=\frac 2 9(3u+2v)$$
$$f(e_2)=\frac 1 9\left(\matrix{10\cr13\cr}\right)$$

We can deduce the matrix of the linear transformation
$$A=\frac 1 9\left(\matrix{22&10\cr-20&13\cr}\right)$$

Comment: I'm sorry can you explain how you got (1/9)(8u+v), where does that come from?

Comment: Well I try to make the vector e1 from a linear combinations of vectors u and v. I will be able to do that because u and v are not colinear. I know I want the y to be 0 so  i know i have to take 8 u + v. But this gives me the vector (9,0) so i divide by 9 to get (1,0). If you cannot do it like this just write down the system of two equations au+bv=e1 were a and b are real numbers (the two equations being the projection of au+bv=e1 on x and on y) and solve for a and b. If I didnt do any mistakes you should find the same values I find.